# Transfer all options of "geometry" to my package

Tags: package-writing, package-options

In my package I need to use all of `geometry` package  options, I can define one  option `landscape` like this

```
\DeclareOption{landscape}{
    \geometry{landscape}
} 

\ProcessOptions\relax
```

My hope is to find a simple way  to  insert all of them as options in my package

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}[2018/02/14]

\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage[totpages,user]{zref}
\RequirePackage[explicit,compact]{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}


\DeclareOption{landscape}{
    \geometry{landscape}
}

\DeclareOption*{\PackageWarning{mypackage}{Unknown ‘\CurrentOption’ option}}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\def\foo{foo}

\endinput
```

Comment: I don't know a way to do this automatically for all Options. But you should use something like \DeclareVoidOption{}{}{} for declaring Option without a value and the command \PassOptionsToPackage{}{} for telling the package what to do. Here an example: \DeclareVoidOption{landscape}{\PassOptionsToPackage{landscape}{geometry}}.

Comment: I forgot to mention that if you use \DeclareVoidOption{}{} you need the package kvoptions.

Answer (score 2):

If it is only one package you need all the options then you can do something like this:

```
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToPackage{\CurrentOption}{geometry}}
```

Because \DeclareOption* is the command which is used when no other previous defined option was detected.